# Interprocess mutex with pthreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to use a mutex which will be used to synchronize access to some variables residing in the memory shared b/w two different processes. How can I achieve that. Code sample to perform that will be very appreciated.

Comment: Why does your title say "pthreads" but you are asking about "processes"? How are you sharing memory between processes anyway, with memory mapping?

Comment: I'm sharing memory by allocating it before forking. So one process is the parent and the other is child. By pthread, I meant using pthread_mutex_lock.

Comment: I think `fork` creates _copies_ of the memory, so it's not exactly "shared".

Comment: Kerrek SB, actually i attach shared memory by using shmget and shmat before forking, so they get mapped to the same address in both processes!

Comment: @KerrekSB Operating systems don't care as much as you probably think about the distinction between threads and processes.  In Linux, they are all 'clone'd anyways.

Comment: @MetallicPriest You should use POSIX shared memory (shm_open) instead of Sys5 (shmget).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Use a [POSIX semaphore](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) initialized to `1` instead.</strike> (See below) Use `sem_init` for unnamed semaphores or `sem_open` for named ones.

```
sem_t sem;

/* initialize using sem_init or sem_open */

sem_wait(&sem);
/* critical region */
sem_post(&sem);
```

---

Many years after initially posting this answer, it has to be updated.

**Mutexes should actually be used instead of semaphores**. R and kuga's comments (copied verbatim below) explain why. In particular I find kuga's mention that mutexes can only be `post`ed by their locking thread most compelling.

---

R

> sem_init requires a nonzero pshared argument to be shared, just like a
>   mutex would require the pshared attribute. There's no reason to prefer
>   semaphores over mutexes for this, and in fact mutexes would be better
>   because you could use a robust mutex which allows you to handle the
>   (very real!) case where one process dies while holding the lock.

kuga

> Additionally to R..`s post, a mutex can only be posted by the thread
>   that locks it. This is often required and a semaphore does not provide
>   this feature. So this is not the correct answer, Jeff´s answer should
>   be flagged as the correct answer.

Comment: @MetallicPriest Enough for what ? Put more effort into your questions

Comment: I mean, would the variable of type sem_t require some special initialization to make it work for inter process communication.

Comment: Did you actually read my answer ? "*Use sem_init for unnamed semaphores or sem_open for named ones*".

Comment: `sem_init` requires a nonzero pshared argument to be shared, just like a mutex would require the pshared attribute. There's no reason to prefer semaphores over mutexes for this, and in fact mutexes would be better because you could use a robust mutex which allows you to handle the (very real!) case where one process dies while holding the lock.

Comment: @R.. I actually didn't know pthread mutexes can be shared across processes :-) Of course, you're absolutely right.

Comment: -1 as a justification on why `sem_t` should be preferred over `pthread mutexes` is missing, or, alternatively, a note on the possibility of using `pthread mutexes`.

Comment: Additionally to R..`s post, a mutex can only be posted by the thread that locks it. This is often required and a semaphore does not provide this feature. So this is not the correct answer, Jeff´s answer should be flagged as the correct answer.

Comment: @kuga Thanks a lot for that, I didn't know. I edited the answer and included your mention. Can you add a link to some documentation?

Comment: Actually its a litte bit more complicated ;) see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html. You should probably activate the PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK setting.

Answer (score 15):

The following example demonstrates the creation, use and destruction of a Pthread interprocess mutex.  Generalizing the example for multiple processes is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t shm_mutex;

int main(void)
{
    int err;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    err = pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutex_init(&shm_mutex, &attr); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutex_lock(&shm_mutex); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm_mutex); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutex_destroy(&shm_mutex); if (err) return err;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know why folks downvote this answer.  I don't show how to create processes because that is a mostly orthogonal issue.  It's also context-dependent.  I'm an HPC programmer, so I create processes with MPI.  Others might want an example using fork() or exec().  I'm less qualified to write those examples.

Comment: because it is wrong! The mutex must be placed at shared memory(anoymous or file mapped) but not a global var.

Comment: Do you notice that the code is demonstrating the API usage and very explicitly not showing a complete example? Hence the part that is left as an exercise to the reader?

Comment: This even is not a good demo. Declaring shm_mutex as a simple global var won't work. This can confuse readers.

Comment: You are correct that my code cannot be copy-pasted into a nontrivial application, but it is correct as written, because a global variable is legal when the code runs as a single process, which is explicitly stated in the answer already.  If you have something constructive to say, why not answer the question yourself with something that meets your standards.

Comment: I'm not denying your answer. I am suggesting you should make it clear how the shared mutex can be created. This is one of the key point of this problem. You can even simply add pesudo code.

Comment: The question is about an interprocess mutex  , the answer should show that rather than claiming "this is a single process mutex, you have to figure out yourself how to do an interprocess one"

Comment: @M.M `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED)` is exactly the creation of an *interprocess mutex*.  What is not shown is the separate question of creating multiple processes.  The OP did not ask how to create processes, so I did not not answer that.

Comment: I deleted this answer for ~1.5 years because of the pointless hate I got from you two.  Please keep hating if you want me to delete it again.

Comment: Recommendations on how to improve the answer aren't "pointless hate". You can always mark the answer as "community wiki" if you don't want to get notifications for comments on it

Comment: Scroll up and hit the `edit` button. Actually make the world a better place instead of continuously whining at me that I interpret the question differently than you do.

Answer (score 1):

As the reply from Changbin Du in the previous answer,

> The mutex must be placed at shared memory(anoymous or file mapped) but not a global var.

Here is the demo:

```cpp
// The mutex must be placed at shared memory(anoymous or file mapped) but not a global var
pthread_mutex_t *shm_lock;

void child_start()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(shm_lock);

   printf("Child process has started\n");
   sleep(1);
   printf("Child process has finished\n");

   pthread_mutex_unlock(shm_lock);
}

void parent_start()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(shm_lock);

   printf("Parent process has started\n");
   sleep(1);
   printf("Parent process has finished\n");

   pthread_mutex_unlock(shm_lock);
}

int main(void)
{
   // init shared lock at anoymous shared memory
   shm_lock = (pthread_mutex_t*) mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

   pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
   pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
   pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
   pthread_mutex_init(shm_lock, &attr);
   pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

   pid_t pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0)
   {
      child_start();
      return 0;
   }

   parent_start();
   wait(NULL);

   pthread_mutex_destroy(shm_lock);
   return 0;
}
```

Then, the correct log will be printed.

```sh
Parent process has started
Parent process has finished
Child process has started
Child process has finished
```