# C Communication between process

Tags: c, linux, communication, system-calls

My university professor has asked me to develop a project in C for Unix machines.
I should do a soccer championship emulator, in which there is a parent, and there are some child(every match between two teams).
The parent must create the matches, and the matches must tell the end result to the parent.

I think the best thing to do is to use fork() syscall and unnamed pipes.

What do you think about?

Thanks

Comment: unnamed pipes will work, but note that a pipe is uni-directional.  If you want bi-directional communication over a single file-descriptor, you might want to use socketpair() instead.

Comment: So, i can use only one socketpair() instead of using one pipe for every match/child?

Comment: One socketpair per child (creating two file descriptors per child), rather than two pipes per child (creating four file descriptors per child).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion above is valid. That approach would work. It might be easier to use a chunk of shared memory and mutex instead, but it's ultimately your call. I've included a working example that uses `pthread_mutex` calls and `mmap` in the references below that should get you up and running. Good luck!

**References**

---

1. *C procs, fork(), and mutexes*, Accessed 2014-04-29, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172541/procs-fork-and-mutexes>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172541/procs-fork-and-mutexes)