# Using pthread mutex shared between processes correctly

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

There are many questions on stackoverflow about if a pthread mutex can be shared between processes, but I found no questions/answers regarding initialization of the shared mutex.

As far as I understand, the common way of using a process-shared mutex is the following: allocate a block of shared memory, initialize a pthread mutex on the shared memory block, use it.

In case of shared memory creation, it is handled by OS if multiple processes try to allocate a shared memory block with the same key ID. OK, but what I don't understand is how can I initialize a mutex on the shared memory block safely?

Am I right that the pthread_mutex_init doesn't provide any safe approach to initialize the pthread_mutex_t simultaneously from different processes? If yes, how can I provide exclusive access for processes to initialize a shared "mutual exclusion"? And how can I make sure if another process initialized the mutex successfully or not?

The second question relates to a case when a process blocking a mutex crashes. OK, there is a robust mutex which handles such cases and returns a corresponding error code. What about the shared memory block? It seems like a process should take care about if it is the last process which uses the shared memory to destroy it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use POSIX semaphores instead? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html  Unlike pthread_mutex, POSIX semaphores are _intended_ for inter-process communication.

Comment: @jameslarge This is a good question. Some people advise to use mutexes instead of semaphores. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6477525/465662 I'm trying to find any real advantages

Comment: @Rom098, It is better in terms of OS scheduling perspective. Mutex has a clear ownership hence scheduler can know which process to schedule (schedule a process that has lock.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Am I right that the pthread_mutex_init doesn't provide any safe approach to initialize the pthread_mutex_t simultaneously from different processes?*

Correct.  It is up to you to ensure that only one process calls `pthread_mutex_init()` on the mutex, and that no process tries to operate on the mutex until that call has successfully returned.

For example, with POSIX `shm_open()` shared memory regions, you can have the processes try to open the region with the `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` flags, so that exactly one process will succeed in creating it.  This process is then responsible for resizing the shared memory region and initialising the mutex with `pthread_mutex_init()`.  The other processes must then wait for some kind of notification from the initialising process before opening the shared memory region - eg you could have the processes block opening a FIFO `O_RDONLY`, and have the initialising process notify them by opening the FIFO `O_WRONLY` (which will cause the open to succeed).

Usually, a shared memory segment will not be the only communication channel between the processes.  Typically you would bootstrap the communication through a UNIX domain socket and negotiate the setup of the shared memory region over it, probably even passing the shared memory region file descriptor through the socket with a `SCM_RIGHTS` message.  The shared memory region would then be used to accelerate the performance-sensitive IPC.

Comment: Can one not use the pthread_once(3) to achieve init safely? I know one can for threads of a given process; would it work across processes assuming the 'once_control' variable is also in shared memory?

Comment: @kaiwan: POSIX only says that `pthread_once()` works between threads of the same process.  It does say that the `pthread_once_t` variable has to be statically initialized which is a problem for placing it in a shared memory area.

Comment: We need to handle the case when process which created the shared memory crashes before notifying other processes.

Comment: What would happen when if system restarts? Then do we need to reinitialize that file containing the mutex?

Answer (score 6):

I use `mmap` to create a shared memory block.

```
int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);
```

when the file does not exist, then `fd < 0`, then I try to initialize a mutex memory.

```
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_CLOEXEC | O_TRUNC | O_EXCL,
            S_IRUSR);
if(fd < 0) {
     // two processes might try to create the file simultaneously.
     // one open is success, the other one fail because of O_EXCL.
     sleep_random_10ms();
     continue; // continue and try again.
}
```

Note: because of `S_IRUSR`, after `open` is success and the file is created, the file is still not writable. Any other processes will not be able to open the file with `O_RDWR`, so that the first `open` still fail. No process will use the mutex while we are initializing the mutex.

after the file is created, we initialize a mutex as usual

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&att);
pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&att);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&att, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &att)
write(fd, &mutex, sizeof(mutex))
fchmod(fd, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)
close(fd);
```

The last two steps make the file writable so that any other process will open the file successfully at the first attempt.

We start to use the mutex as usual

```
mutex = (pthread_mutex_t*) mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_, 0);
pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
....
pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
```

to clean up

```
munmap(&mutex);
close(fd);
```

Comment: Looks pretty good solution to me. I hope if someone has used it and then they should provide their feedback.

Comment: Note you don't really need  a file. `shm_open` would be better.

Comment: I suppose the processes using the shared-memory will lock up if the creator dies between open() and fchmod(). But I have yet to find an alternative that doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I wrote [an implementation](https://github.com/hnakamur/luajit-pshared-mmapf-experiment) in [LuaJIT](https://luajit.org/) and it seems working as expected. Thanks!
I changed it a bit, used `O_SYNC` open flag and initialize a mutex on the shared memory instead of using `write` syscall.

Comment: I also wrote an example using `shm_open` (instead of `open`) and `pthread_rwlock_t` (instead of `pthread_mutex_t`).